# Stabilizing variance and dependence of data on its mean

Tags: variance, feature-engineering

I am reading *Practical Machine Learning with Python*, about feature engineering, section *Statistical Transformations*. This sections starts with the following lines

> Let’s look at a different strategy of feature engineering on numerical data by using statistical or mathematical
>   transformations. In this section, we will look at the Log transform as well as the Box-Cox transform. Both of
>   these transform functions belong to the Power Transform family of functions. These functions are typically
>   used to create monotonic data transformations, but their main significance is that they help in stabilizing
>   variance, adhering closely to the normal distribution and making the data independent of the mean based
>   on its distribution.

I have two questions, and since they are similar I am asking in a single post.

Q1: I know what variance is but I don't understand what "stabilizing variance" is. How do we determine if a variance is "stable" or not? Any explanation with an example or reference would be helpful.

Q2: What does it mean for data being "independent of the mean"? Isn't the mean a function of (numeric) data, and so it is mean that depends on data? I can't imagine how data can depend on its mean.

Comment: This isn't something you could have guessed at, but a search for [spread + leve](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=spread+level) will turn up many examples and relevant explanations.